# DOM and events, find right element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to write a function that takes a blog id as argument (e.g. `'blog-1'` and `'blog-2'`), and then, from the element with an id that matches the argument, the function needs to select all the elements that has the attribute `class="content"`. Finally, the function needs to return the elements obtained from the previous step.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Our Amazing Blogs</h2>
    <div id="blog-1">
      <h3>How to prepare the perfect pizza</h3>
      <p class="content">
        The secret for preparing the perfect pizza is.... #!/*?@, and ####@@@!</br>
        So you just have to $%!?#**- it!
      </p>
      <p class="content">
        <u>Upgrade to Pro to uncover the full post</u>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="blog-2">
      <h3>My life as a shrimp</h3>
      <p class="content">
        Few years back I got tired of all the pressure put on me just for the fact of being a human being.
        Why does society expect you to behave like a person just for the fact of being one?!
        So I decided to turn myself into a shrimp and what happend next is amazing...
      </p>
      <p class="content">
        <u>Upgrade to Pro to uncover the full post</u>
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript base:

```js
function getContentFromBlog(blogId) {
  // Get the right div according to the given blogid
  let blog = "Replace this string with the expression to get the blog div";
  // Get all elements with content class from the blog div
  let content = "Replace this string with the expression to get the elements with 'content' class from the blog div";
  // Write the return statement to return content
}
```

Comment: What have you tried until now? Show us any attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getContentFromBlog(blogid) {
  const div = document.querySelectorAll(`div#${blogid} p.content`);
  if (!div) {
    return;
  }
  return Array.from(div).map((ele) => ele.textContent.split("\n").join(''));
}
console.log(getContentFromBlog("blog-1"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Our Amazing Blogs</h2>

  <div id="blog-1">
  
    <h3>How to prepare the perfect pizza</h3>
  
    <p class="content">
      The secret for preparing the perfect pizza is.... #!/*?@, and ####@@@!</br>
      So you just have to $%!?#**- it!
    </p>
  
    <p class="content">
      <u>Upgrade to Pro to uncover the full post</u>
    </p>
    </div>

  <div id="blog-2">
  
    <h3>My life as a shrimp</h3>
  
    <p class="content">
      Few years back I got tired of all the pressure put on me just for the fact of being a human being. Why does society expect you to behave like a person just for the fact of being one?! So I decided to turn myself into a shrimp and what happend next is
      amazing...
    </p>
  
    <p class="content">
      <u>Upgrade to Pro to uncover the full post</u>
    </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```